# Arrow keys not detected once the SWF file is published

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm using flash CS4 to have an animated character moving within the stage boundaries. There are no code errors when generating the SWF file and the character is moving fine when I test the movie in Flash. Once I publish the file, the character is completely unresponsive to the arrow keys. I have no clue as what the issue might be and some help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the code of the movie :

```
stop();

var upPressed:Boolean = false;
var downPressed:Boolean = false;
var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
var isWalking:Boolean = false;
var mySpeed:Number = 3;

my_Sprite.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveSprite);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, setKeyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, unsetKeyPressed);

function moveSprite(event:Event):void {
    if(upPressed && my_Sprite.y >= 40){
        my_Sprite.y -= mySpeed;
    }
    if(downPressed && my_Sprite.y <= 440){
        my_Sprite.y += mySpeed;
    }
    if(leftPressed && my_Sprite.x >= 20){
        my_Sprite.x -= mySpeed;
    }
    if(rightPressed && my_Sprite.x <= 600){
        my_Sprite.x += mySpeed;
    }
}

function setKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    switch(event.keyCode){
        case Keyboard.UP: {
            upPressed = true;
      if (!isWalking) {        
  my_Sprite.gotoAndPlay("Up");
              isWalking = true;
          }
          break;
       }

       case Keyboard.DOWN: {
          downPressed = true;
          if (!isWalking) {        
              my_Sprite.gotoAndPlay("Down");
              isWalking = true;
          }
          break;
       }

       case Keyboard.LEFT: {
           leftPressed = true;
           if (!isWalking) {           
               my_Sprite.gotoAndPlay("Left");
               isWalking = true;
          }
          break;
       }  

       case Keyboard.RIGHT: {
           rightPressed = true;
           if (!isWalking) {           
               my_Sprite.gotoAndPlay("Right");
               isWalking = true;
          }
          break;
       }  

    }
}


function unsetKeyPressed(event:KeyboardEvent):void {

    switch(event.keyCode) {

       case Keyboard.UP: {
                 upPressed = false;
           my_Sprite.gotoAndStop("Up");
           isWalking = false;
           break;
       }

       case Keyboard.DOWN: {
                 downPressed = false;
           my_Sprite.gotoAndStop("Down");
           isWalking = false;
           break;
       }

       case Keyboard.LEFT: {
                 leftPressed = false;
           my_Sprite.gotoAndStop("Left");
           isWalking = false;
           break;
       }

       case Keyboard.RIGHT: {
                 rightPressed = false;
           my_Sprite.gotoAndStop("Right");
           isWalking = false;
           break;
       }  

    }
}
```

Comment: If you are running your SWF in a browser window, you may need to click on the flash object before it can accept keyboard input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add some JavaScript to your HTML to set the focus on the Flash object:

`<body onLoad="window.document.movieID.focus();">`

Make sure you change `movieID` to whatever you actually set as your ID.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, I still have to click first on my movie then it runs OK. Is this the only way to force the focus or is there a way to code it directly in Flash ? I'm afraid I'm less comfortable with HTML or JS

Comment: It didn't work because my initial object tag contained a space. So I changed the name  and it now works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can force the focus by doing

```
this.stage.focus = myTextField; // assuming this is added to the display hierarchy
```